# Laravel Email Configuration Issue - removed mail gun, from still noting mailgun

Tags: php, email, laravel

I can currently send email but for some odd reason the from message looks like this...

```
noreply=myWebsite.com@mailgun.org <noreply=myWebsite.com@mailgun.org>
```

But my config file reads as follows...

```
    'driver' => 'mail',
    'host' => '',
    'port' => 587,
    'from' => array('address' => 'noreply@myWebsite.com', 'name' => 'My Website'),
    'encryption' => 'tls',
```

I thought mail was just native php email. I am just trying to understand why it still references mailgun despite the removal of smtp as driver.

What I noticed on the actualy email I receive it says that its from "My Website" followed by "sent by noreply=myWebsite.com@mailgun.org". If I click respond to "My Website" the email address is correct "noreply@mywebsite.com". I just don't understand why I can't get it not to show the sent by message. Any advice?